# Best way to schedule structure schema design of a events database

Tags: database-design, schema

On this case at the events table has a repeated schedule and scheduled by date

example case each of event schedule:

- The event has schedule every month, week and day with start and end of time
- The event has schedule every working days and working hours
- The event has date range schedule
- The event has a date for once converence

for following these problem, I'm so confusing to create the dynamic scheme for these condition

### Table structure

**events table column**

- id PK
- title
- location

**event_schedules**

I create this scheme referenced from crontab scheduling where it can be create every year, month, week, day, or custom date. And the other condition I would to record event shedule with other option

- id PK
- event_id FK events_table_event_id
- year
- month
- week
- day
- custom_date
- start_time
- end_time

### Question

What the best way to handle these data structure problem? I need some reference for taking these problem.